# What does an aura around a selection icon mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently, I noticed that when you hold your finger on the pokeball icon at the bottom of the map screen, then drag your finger to either the 'items', 'pokemon', 'shop' or 'pokedex' icons without letting go, a hoop appears around the icon you are touching. Is this purely for decoration, or is there some significance towards the gameplay itself?

[image: Looks a bit like this]

Comment: As on Stack Exchange Meta says, _please explain what is wrong with this question!_ It is annoying, as I have posted this, and I have only received 1 downvote. Just Explain!

Comment: People tend to downvote things that they don't see as having a lot of effort put into them. There's also a bit of a bias against PokemonGo questions on this site nowadays, it seems.

Comment: AFAIK you are not required to give an explanation to why you downvote (I didn't just informing you)

Comment: FWIW this actually isn't a recent thing. A lot of trainers discovered this early on, but it still unknown what the purpose of it is

Answer (score 10):

If you release the screen with that item selected, the behavior is the same as if you had tapped the Poke ball normally, then tapped the selected item normally. It's a shortcut to get to the Pokémon, Pokedex, Shop, and Items menus.

- **Swipe Pokeball left**: Open Pokemon menu
- **Swipe Pokeball right**: Open Items menu
- **Swipe Pokeball up**: Open Shop menu
- **Swipe Pokeball further up**: Open Pokedex menu

Comment: It's not a shortcut; it's just another way.

Comment: I mean shortcut in the sense that a swipe is a single action, shorter than two separate taps (with a delay in between as the buttons load)

Comment: I may have misunderstood but I want evidence of _gameplay significance_ or _no effect_

Answer (score 3):

The icon outline is a visual cue from a swipe gesture, informing you of a selection.  Each of the four options also uses a different colored outline.  If you use the tap gesture, then the visual cue is unnecessary.